# Replace live wordpress database with my new updated local database - phpMyAdmin

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, publish

I have created a new updated version of my website locally and now I want to publish it and overwrite my old database that is currently live.

It's a wordpress site and during my development I have changed the structure of post types and taxonomies (delting, editing and rearranging) and I have also installed and deleted some plugins.

What is the best way to update my current live database with my new local database?

Answer (score 1):

Just apply below SQL query in you live server phpmyadmin.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.live.com', 'http://www.local.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.live.com','http://www.local.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.live.com', 'http://www.local.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.live.com','http://www.local.com');
```